# Datepicker onchange submit with default value

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm trying to assign default value to Gijgo Datepicker but it submit the form each time I click on it, means that I cannot change the value.

```js
var today, datepicker;
  today = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getDate());

  datepicker = $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    header: true, 
    uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
      format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
      minDate: '2020-01-01',
      value: '2020-02-01', //add this and it broke
      showRightIcon: true,
      iconsLibrary: 'fontawesome',
      maxDate: today,
      change: function (e) { $('form').submit();}
 });
```

```html
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.13/js/gijgo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.13/css/gijgo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    
  <form action="" method="get" autocomplete="off">
    <input id="datepicker" class="" width="276" name="date" />
  </form>
```

It worked but when I don't assign the value, what I need is to show a current month so user don't have to choose the month again. Anything I tried just broke the input.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's your `change: function (e) { $('form').submit()};` doing this - seems it's submitting the form as soon as you change the input: see below code for solution.

EDIT: Op is asking for a way to listen to submit the form when the user clicks a specific date.

You can do this by leveraging [bootstrap datepicker events](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html)

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker()
    .on('changeDate', function(e) {
        // `e` here contains the extra attributes
        if(e.date === yourDate) 
            $('form').submit()
    });
```

```js
var today, datepicker;
  today = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getDate());

  datepicker = $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    header: true, 
    uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
      format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
      minDate: '2020-01-01',
      showRightIcon: true,
      iconsLibrary: 'fontawesome',
      maxDate: today
 });
```

```html
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.13/js/gijgo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.13/css/gijgo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    
  <form action="" method="get" autocomplete="off">
    <input value="2020-02-01" id="datepicker" class="" width="276" name="date" />
  </form>
```

Comment: Yes, but is there any solution that can submit the form after user click on specific date?

Comment: You should be able to do this... I will update my answer.